# Frequent xhr request by socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

When I connect to the socket server from the client side, which is considered react, every few seconds a repeated request is sent by the socket client. Generally, the requests are of get type and most of the time they are in pending mode. Sometimes the result of requests is 2.
What do you think is the problem of sending repeated requests after connecting or doing anything with the socket?

**UPDATE**

This problem occurs when I use namespace . I tried all the solutions but this problem was not solved.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jkXC.png)

Comment: this is how it works. you can read everything here https://socket.io/docs/v3/how-it-works/

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior when the option used for transport is ***polling*** (long-polling).

What happens is, by default, the transport parameter is `["polling", "websocket"]` ([client](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#transports), [server](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#transports)), where the sequence of elements matters. So, the first connection attempt is made via *polling* (which is faster to start compared to websocket), and then (or in parallel, I don't know the working details) there is a connection attempt by *websocket* (this takes a little longer to establish but is faster for later communication).

If the *websocket* connection is successfully established, the communication will be carried in this way. But if an error occurs, or the connection takes a long time to be established, or this transport option is not present in the instance's parameters, then the communication will continue being carried out through *polling*, which are the various requests that remain pending. It is normal for them to remain pending, so they receive an update and are able to inform the requester immediately, without the need for several quick requests consulting the application's status.

Check the instance parameters you set for this connection to find out if transport via *websocket* is enabled. Be careful when using the socket server behind a **reverse proxy**, as this reverse proxy needs to be properly configured to accept *websocket* connections, otherwise it won't work.

You can check the websocket requests in the browser inspection, Network tab, by enabling the `WS` filter.

---

Here are some additional links for you to read more about:

- https://socket.io/docs/v4/how-it-works/
- https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/
- https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/
- https://ably.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling